# MariaDB connection fails randomly but stady

Tags: junit, mariadb, testcontainers

I'm running my junit tests in Ubuntu 20 TLS in Eclipse.

Setup:

- mariadb in docker container with testcontainers.org
- Spring 5 Application in embedded jetty (for junit tests only)

I was wondering why my embedded jetty runs into failures with connectivity to the database:

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
```

I analysed this for days (and nights :( ) ... nothing found.

So I wrote a test harness to find out, whether the testcontainers setup could be a problem, and - unfortunately - it seems to be:

If i try to connect, call a statement, disconnect and repeat this, mariadb in container seems to refuse the connection after a while.

```
package de.enno.testcontainers_mariadb;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.testcontainers.containers.MariaDBContainer;

public class MariaDBTest {

    @Rule
    public MariaDBContainer mariaDB = new MariaDBContainer("mariadb:10.3.6").withUsername("test").withPassword("test");

    @Test
    public void test() throws SQLException {

        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(mariaDB.getJdbcUrl(), "test", "test");
        Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
        stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE a (id int not null primary key, value varchar(20))");
        stmt.close();
        connection.close();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
            if (i % 1000 == 0) {
                System.err.println("Connect " + i + "...");
            }
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(mariaDB.getJdbcUrl(), "test", "test");
            stmt = connection.createStatement();
            stmt.execute("SELECT * FROM a");
            stmt.close();
            connection.close();
        }
    }

}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <groupId>de.enno</groupId>
    <artifactId>testcontainers-mariadb</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <name>testcontainers-mariadb app</name>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.11</source>
                    <target>1.11</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb</artifactId>
            <version>1.15.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

```
...
Connect 0...
Connect 1000...
Connect 2000...
Connect 3000...
Connect 4000...
Connect 5000...
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not connect to address=(host=localhost)(port=33135)(type=master) : Read timed out
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:73)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.create(ExceptionFactory.java:192)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connectWithoutProxy(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1392)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.Utils.retrieveProxy(Utils.java:635)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbConnection.newConnection(MariaDbConnection.java:150)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:89)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:228)
    at de.enno.testcontainers_mariadb.MariaDBTest.test(MariaDBTest.java:30)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.FailureDetectingExternalResource$1.evaluate(FailureDetectingExternalResource.java:30)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Read timed out
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.handleIoException(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:2075)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.readPacket(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1529)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.getResult(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1508)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.readPipelineAdditionalData(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1031)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.postConnectionQueries(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:880)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.createConnection(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:595)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connectWithoutProxy(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1387)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:115)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140)
    at java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.io.input.ReadAheadBufferedStream.fillBuffer(ReadAheadBufferedStream.java:131)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.io.input.ReadAheadBufferedStream.read(ReadAheadBufferedStream.java:104)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.io.input.StandardPacketInputStream.getPacketArray(StandardPacketInputStream.java:247)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.io.input.StandardPacketInputStream.getPacket(StandardPacketInputStream.java:218)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.readPacket(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1527)
    ... 36 more
```

It seems to be not a timeout problem - in some cases the test runs for some seconds, and some times it runs for hours, BUT: it happens *always*

Any ideas, how to solve this?

Thanx in advice !

[update]: when trying to connect to the mariadb after the error occured, the connection is established again.

Comment: have you configured  mariadb's maximium connection or connection backlog? How many concurrent connections? Why such an old mariadb-10.3 versoin?

Comment: Hi @dankblack, thank you for help and your fast answer.

I tried it with newer Version (10.5) with the same result

```show GLOBAL variables like 'back_log';``` delivers
```
| back_log      | 80    |
```
... should be enough, doesn't it?

Max Connections:
show status like '%onn%';
```
Connections                                   | 21695 |
Max_used_connections                          | 2     |
threads_connected                             | 1     |
Aborted_connects                              | 0     |
```

What do you mean with "connection backlog" ...?

Comment: With max_used_connections on 2 [back_log](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#back_log) doesn't come into play (which is what I meant by connection backlog). Set [max_error_count](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#max_error_count) to maximum maybe. Can't hurt.

Comment: Just out of curiosity - why do you create a new connection, what is the use case? Usually a new container is created for every test method since it's not a static field in your test class. 

I mean are your tests short or do you run a lot of queries in some tests and that causes connection error after a while?

Comment: Hi@danblack: i traced the timestamps; average = 1 or 2 ms to connect. 
BUT: _NO_ connect takes longer than 500ms. So i guess, the client lib interrupts the connection, if it takes longer than 500ms to connect (which seems to happen when maybe the server side is cleaning up, garbage collection or whatever?) - do you know wether there is an option set by default for this - or if this is hard coded somewhere maybe?

Thank for very much !!!

Comment: @dankblack

- Connect 0... avg=0 max=0
- Connect 1000... avg=1 max=10
- Connect 2000... avg=1 max=7
(...)
- Connect 10000... avg=0 max=7
(...)
- Connect 11000... avg=0 max=10
- Connect 12000... avg=1 max=501
- Connect 13000... avg=0 max=11
- Connect 14000... avg=2 max=502
- Connect 15000... avg=2 max=501
- Connect 19000... avg=3 max=504
- Connect 20000... avg=3 max=502

--> Exception connect timeout

- (the timestamp is not recorded in the connection lib, so i think 3/4ms get lost "on the way" to the beginning of the 500ms interruption timer)

Comment: @Vitaly Chura
the code above is just to reproduce the problem. I'm using testcontainers for my long running (realistic) integration tests (running some hours) with several servers for my online / offline system without the connection pool of tomcat. I must be sure that the software works (offline -> updates in case of emergency not possible)

In the test cases the servers are started once and the uses cases are run (selenium) against http frontend of these containers (highly complex use cases with heavy database setups to can test them)

The tests fail randomly because of the behaviour.